# Webview doesnt load my page

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm a beginner on this kinda stuff.
I have a button that when I click on it, it loads a page on `webview`.

The code is the following:

Right now when I'm clicking on the button, the page doesn't load.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web2);

        String url = "http://giae.aeourem.pt";

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
        web.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't say anything about a button.

Comment: any error in a logcat ?

Comment: I don't see any code that is going to load anything into the webView.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. Welcome to StackOverflow